# Bootstrap - Adding legend to well

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently using twitter bootstrap, which is working nicely, but I would like to add a legend to the "well" elements that are used in a form (so that I can have multiple wells, denoting sub-sections on a form).

An example of what my form looks like now is:

[image]

I would like to add a legend so that I can have two separate sections beneath the "Details" heading, for example, but be able to denote what they are for. A legend seems the best way to do this.

The relevant section of the html looks like:

```
<form>
   <div class="row">
        <div class="span6">
        <div class="nonboxy-widget">
            <div class="widget-head">
                <h5>Details</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="widget-content">
                 <div class="widget-box">
                    <div class = 'form-horizontal well'>
                        <fieldset>
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label">Sale Type</label>
                                <div class="controls">
```

When I attempt to add a legend tag to either the fieldset or the `div` with class `form-horizontal well` it renders like a heading inside the box, not like a normal html legend. It renders like:

[image]

with the code

```
<div class = 'form-horizontal well'>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Details</legend>
    <div class="control-group">
```

Can anyone recommend a way to get this to render like a normal legend, on the border of the box?

EDIT: Thanks to the code from Simbirsk, I now have:

[image]

This is pretty close, but what I wanted was to have the legend look like a normal html legend on a fieldset (i.e. for it to sit in the border), so I changed the CSS to:

```
legend {
padding: 0;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-bottom: -9px;
border: 0;
color: #999999;
background-color: #333333;
}
```

but that resulted in this:

[image]

How can I ensure that the border on the well "breaks" (is not displayed behind the text) like a normal fieldset legend?

EDIT 2: Following the edit to the first answer, I applied the code to my css and ended up with:

[image]

You will note this is not quite what I was looking for - I am trying to get the legend on the border of the well div, not on the fieldset itself (because this is a nested form, there could be multiple fieldsets within one well, so I can't put the border on the fieldset itself).

I seemed to have achieved this with the code above, the only problem was putting a break in the border where the legend is - can this be done with some kind of opacity to the background of the legend text, and a bit of padding?

Any further suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Legend shall be used along with Fieldset, if you want to create sub-ssections of your from, you shall use fieldsets with their corresponding legend. Your form shall also be enclosed inside <form></form> tags and not divs. If you want to modify the legend style according to your wishes, then create an ID for it and declare a style for it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment - my form has <form> tags, but they were not relevant to the rendering of the legend, so I did not show them in the code. I will edit to avoid confusion. My question is specifically how to create a style that will allow it to be shown on the border of the box - can you assist?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Put the `.well` on the `fieldset` and override Bootstrap's `legend` and `fieldset` styles.
HTML

```
<form>
    <fieldset class="well the-fieldset">
        <legend class="the-legend">Your legend</legend>
        ... your inputs ...
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

CSS

```
.the-legend {
    border-style: none;
    border-width: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.the-fieldset {
    border: 2px groove threedface #444;
    -webkit-box-shadow:  0px 0px 0px 0px #000;
            box-shadow:  0px 0px 0px 0px #000;
}
```

NOTE: I've ommited Bootstrap classes like rows, spans, controls, etc. Use them to fit your layout.
EDIT: Changed code to include `fieldset` styles "reset".

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I have updated the question with the results, it might require a little refinement.

Comment: Updated to recover standard fieldset border behaviour

Comment: +1 for @HO taking your answer, using it, and then accepting his own non-answer without even providing the code.  Someone with that high of a rep should know better.

Comment: With Bootstrap 3.2, I had to also add "width:inherit" to my legend element to fix a problem where the legend was effectively rendering with 100% width, hiding most of the top outline of the fieldset. Credit for that solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16852571/12484

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me in what I was trying to achieve as a groupbox in Bootstrap.

```css
fieldset {
  min-width: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}
.well {
  min-height: 20px;
  padding: 19px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}
.well-legend {
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: auto;
  padding: 2px 7px 2px 5px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  line-height: inherit;
  color: #333;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset class="well">
    <legend class="well-legend">Group Box Legend</legend>
    ... your inputs ...
  </fieldset>
</form>
```