# Use Fieldset Legend with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap for my `JSP` page.

I want to use *`<fieldset>`* and *`<legend>`* for my form. This is my code.

```
<fieldset class="scheduler-border">
    <legend class="scheduler-border">Start Time</legend>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label input-label" for="startTime">Start :</label>
        <div class="controls bootstrap-timepicker">
            <input type="text" class="datetime" id="startTime" name="startTime" placeholder="Start Time" />
            <i class="icon-time"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

CSS is

```css
fieldset.scheduler-border {
    border: 1px groove #ddd !important;
    padding: 0 1.4em 1.4em 1.4em !important;
    margin: 0 0 1.5em 0 !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow:  0px 0px 0px 0px #000;
            box-shadow:  0px 0px 0px 0px #000;
}

legend.scheduler-border {
    font-size: 1.2em !important;
    font-weight: bold !important;
    text-align: left !important;
}
```

I am getting output like this
[image]

I want output in the following way

[image]

I tried adding

```css
border:none;
width:100px;
```

to `legend.scheduler-border` in CSS. And I'm getting the expected output. But the problem is I would like to add another *`<fieldset>`* for another fields. That time the width of text in legend is a problem as it is lengthier than than `100px`.

So what shall I do to get output like I have mentioned? (Without striking the legend text)

Comment: The code you shared seems to work fine. [Here's a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W8rxp/)

Comment: @Aquillo your Fiddle isn't using Bootstrap.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Noticed it too that this is caused by Bootstrap ;)

Comment: I think you should consider to use Bootstrap's panel. It has very similar behavior like fieldset and legend, but more stylish.

Answer (score 245, accepted):

That's because Bootstrap by default sets the width of the `legend` element to 100%. You can fix this by changing your `legend.scheduler-border` to also use:

```css
legend.scheduler-border {
    width:inherit; /* Or auto */
    padding:0 10px; /* To give a bit of padding on the left and right */
    border-bottom:none;
}
```

[**JSFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/PgA84/1).

You'll also need to ensure your custom stylesheet is being added *after* Bootstrap to prevent Bootstrap overriding your styling - although your styles here should have higher specificity.

You may also want to add `margin-bottom:0;` to it as well to reduce the gap between the legend and the divider.

Comment: Ftr: for me Bootstrap 3.3.6 also set a `margin-bottom: 20px;` on the `legend`, which pushed it above the fieldset border, instead of placing it on the line. Setting the `margin-bottom: 0;` on the custom `legend.scheduler-border` fixed that easily.

Comment: Thanks. I added "width: initial;" to my css which was I used for my Legend class. I figured this might be better. I get tired of fighting against bootstrap to stop it from messing stuff up! I had 3 different boot strap type css files that all was messing it up. But now its fixed.

Answer (score 157):

In bootstrap 4 it is much easier to have a border on the fieldset that blends with the legend. You don't need custom css to achieve it, it can be done like this:

```
<fieldset class="border p-2">
   <legend  class="w-auto">Your Legend</legend>
</fieldset>
```

which looks like this:
[image: bootstrap 4 fieldset and legend]

Comment: w-auto is not available in Bootstrap 4.0, but it is available in 4.1+

Comment: This is the simplest solution on here.  I would recommend this to any one.

Comment: For bootstrap 5, you need to add this style as well .

legend{
    float: none;
    padding: inherit;
}

Comment: What are the benefits of using `fieldset` and `legend` in forms?

Answer (score 42):

In Bootstrap 5, [modifications](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/32548#issuecomment-767653924) to the default style applied to the legend results in a different rendering than what is obtained with [Bootstrap 4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50487490/13478534), you must then add `float-none` as class of the `<legend>` tag:

```html
<fieldset class="border p-2">
   <legend  class="float-none w-auto">Your Legend</legend>
</fieldset>
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form>
<fieldset class="border p-2">
   <legend  class="float-none w-auto p-2">Your Legend</legend>
   <input type="text">
</fieldset>
</form>
```

[bootstrap](/questions/tagged/bootstrap) [html](/questions/tagged/html) [form](/questions/tagged/form) [fieldset](/questions/tagged/fieldset) [legend](/questions/tagged/legend)

Answer (score 22):

I had this problem and I solved with this way:

```
fieldset.scheduler-border {
    border: solid 1px #DDD !important;
    padding: 0 10px 10px 10px;
    border-bottom: none;
}

legend.scheduler-border {
    width: auto !important;
    border: none;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Answer (score 18):

I had a different approach , used bootstrap panel to show it little more rich. Just to help someone and improve the answer.

```css
.text-on-pannel {
  background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -47px;
  border: 1px solid #337ab7;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.panel {
  /* for text on pannel */
  margin-top: 27px !important;
}

.panel-body {
  padding-top: 30px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <h3 class="text-on-pannel text-primary"><strong class="text-uppercase"> Title </strong></h3>
      <p> Your Code </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
```

This will give below look.
[image]

Note: We need to change the styles in order to use different header size.

Answer (score 8):

Just wanted to summarize all the correct answers above in short. Because I had to spend lot of time to figure out which answer resolves the issue and  what's going on behind the scenes.

There seems to be two problems of fieldset with bootstrap:

1. The `bootstrap` sets the width to the `legend` as 100%. That is why it overlays the top border of the `fieldset`.
2. There's a `bottom border` for the `legend`.

So, all we need to fix this is set the legend width to auto as follows:

```
legend.scheduler-border {
   width: auto; // fixes the problem 1
   border-bottom: none; // fixes the problem 2
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
fieldset.scheduler-border {
  border: 1px groove #ddd !important;
  padding: 0 1.4em 1.4em 1.4em !important;
  margin: 0 0 1.5em 0 !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #000;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #000;
  margin-top: 30px !important;
}

legend.scheduler-border {
  font-size: 1.2em !important;
  font-weight: bold !important;
  text-align: left !important;
  width: auto;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border-bottom: none;
  margin-top: -15px;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <fieldset class="scheduler-border">
        <legend class="scheduler-border">Technical Ameen</legend>
        <h2>Your Work Here</h2>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

if you will not find any proper solution for using legend tag in bootstrap 5

you can use the CSS property for an alternative solution in the legend tag this is an inline CSS example.

```
style="margin-top:-15px; background-color: white; color: black;"
```

also, add this line in the fieldset tag for margin-top

```
 style="margin-top: 30px !important;"
```

[image]

I hope this is a very simple solution for getting legend style with bootstrap 5

Answer (score 0):

```
<fieldset  class="border p-2 form-group">
   <legend class="control-label customer-legend pl-1">Your Legend</legend>
</fieldset>
```

use css:

```
.customer-legend:before {
    left: 100px;
}
```