# twitter bootstrap border title

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Just wanted to know how to give border title using bootstrap? Like the example below.

```
 <div id="form" style="width:350px;">
<fieldset>
    <legend style="color:blue;font-weight:bold;">General Information</legend>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td><span style="text-decoration:underline">C</span>hange Password To:</td>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><span style="text-decoration:underline">C</span>onfirm Password:</td>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
   </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by border title?

Comment: Do you mean "give a title a border"? I don't think this question is exclusive to bootstrap my guess it's related to the built in styles some browsers give to the <legend /> in a form.

Comment: ok i did not know that, yes ..want to add that legend in chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your html, this is the outcome in chrome:

[image]

You could simply control the border on the fieldset:

```
fieldset{
   border:1px solid #cccc;
}
```

Please note though, the positioning of the legend "General Information" is a computed style but it could be overridden.

"[Fieldsets and Legends](http://www.pixy.cz/blogg/clanky/css-fieldsetandlabels.html)"

Answer (score 0):

To inherit bootstrap css properties, simply use the bootstrap css classes on your table. You might want to use:

.table-striped or .table-bordered within your table tag. Eg table class="table-bordered"

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap there are some default css for fieldset and legend that "destroys" that, here is an answer to see the default.
[Use Fieldset Legend with bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16852484/use-fieldset-legend-with-bootstrap)