# Can't put form inside a box in Bootstrap

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, word-wrap, box

I'm trying to create a download form where users can download and filter data according to the date. I want the form to be wrapped inside a box as shown in the example below taken from this [link](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/forms/article.php/3888746/HTML-Forms-From-Basics-to-Style-Layouts.htm).

[image]

I followed the example code, wrapping my form content inside `<fieldset>` tags but my form looks like this:

[image]

I don't know if this is a bug within bootstrap or if some additional styling must be done.

Here is my html code:

```
            <form  role="form" method="post">
            <fieldset>
                <legend> Download Details</legend>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="startdate" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Start date</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <select >
                            <option>Select Date --</option>
                        </select>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <br><br>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="startdate" class="col-sm-2 control-label">End date</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <select >
                              <option>Select Date --</option>
                        </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
               <br>
               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Download</button>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap is adding styles to `fieldset` and `legend` 
You can create a stylesheet that overrides those styles and include that stylesheet after bootstrap.

You can also check this [Stackoverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16852484/use-fieldset-legend-with-bootstrap).