# Match the top and bottom padding in fieldset bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am following the below post to add some css to fieldset and legend in bootstrap.

[Use Fieldset Legend with bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16852484/2246380)

**HTML**

```
<fieldset class=" scheduler-border">
    <legend class="scheduler-border">Start Time</legend>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label col-xs-6 input-label" for="startTime">Start :</label>
        <div class="controls col-xs-6  bootstrap-timepicker">
            <input type="text" class="datetime" type="text" id="startTime" name="startTime" placeholder="Start Time" />
            <i class="icon-time"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

**CSS**

```
fieldset.scheduler-border {
    border: 1px groove  !important;
    padding: 0 1em 1em !important;
    margin: 0 0 0 0 !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow:  0px 0px 0px 0px #000;
            box-shadow:  0px 0px 0px 0px #000;
}
    legend.scheduler-border {
        font-size: 1.1em !important;
        font-weight: bold !important;
        text-align: left !important;
        width:auto;
        padding:0 5px;
        border-top:none;
        border-bottom:none;
    }
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/zpp1u1q5/

Here is how it looks now

[image]

How do I change CSS to reduce the reduce H1 and make it equal to H2 ?

Comment: try using [margin: 0 auto;](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/zpp1u1q5/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first gap is due to `legend`'s `margin-bottom` :

[image]

While the second gap is due to `fieldset`'s `padding-bottom`:

[image]

Adjust one of them to get your desired layout (4px `margin-bottom` on `legend` seems a good fit)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to change the padding-left, here is the solution: 
http://jsfiddle.net/td9o6ecg/

```
<fieldset class=" scheduler-border">
<legend class="scheduler-border">Start Time</legend>
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label col-xs-6 input-label" style="padding-left: 5px;" for="startTime">Start :</label>
    <div class="controls col-xs-6  bootstrap-timepicker">
        <input type="text" class="datetime" type="text" id="startTime" name="startTime" placeholder="Start Time" />
        <i class="icon-time"></i>
    </div>
</div>
</fieldset>
```