# Design issues when combining .panel with FIELDSET and .panel-heading with LEGEND

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, accessibility

For accessibility reasons I need to add `fieldset` and `legend` to Bootstrap's `.panel` element. But sadly, the `legend` can't be styled correctly anymore: the border around `fieldset` only comes to the middle height!

[image: screenshot]

Codepen: http://codepen.io/jmuheim/pen/ByMVwY

Anyone knows how to make the `fieldset.panel-heading` look exactly the same as the `div.panel-heading`?

Comment: Float the `legend` tag http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LEqrBR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add float left to the `legend` tag. Since the width is already set to 100%, it should not cause any issues

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LEqrBR

```
legend.panel-heading {
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    float: left;
}
```

I checked this on FF and Chrome on a Mac, seems fine. To get the spacing right for the body part, you could add a margin to the `legend` tag. For example

```
margin-bottom: 10px;
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dPaKgv

Comment: Floating the legend element means you can't use left or right padding without having overflow and clearing problems.

Comment: @CChoma You can use padding, just add `box-sizing: border-box` to it. See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RNvBNQ There isn't any clearing issues with the way it is used

Answer (score -2):

I attempted something similar yesterday. This post will probably have what you need.

[Use Fieldset Legend with bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16852484/use-fieldset-legend-with-bootstrap)