# Fieldset with border does not look proper in MVC but does in JSFiddle

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, fieldset

I am using a fieldset in an mvc web application that is using Bootstrap, when I run the view the fieldset doesn't look at all like it does when I try it in a fiddle. 
The fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Cwm76/ep10kf8b/) here is the code in the fiddle

```
    #moderatorFieldset{
    border:1px #282DD1 solid;
}
```

and here is the fieldset

```
    <div class="tab-pane" id="AddModerator">
    <br/>
    <fieldset id="moderatorFieldset">
        <legend>Add Moderator</legend>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="txtNewClient" class="control-label col-md-2"><b>Client:</b></label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input id="txtNewClient" type="text" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="ddCatalog" class="control-label col-md-2"><b>Catalog:</b></label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div id="msCatalog"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-6">
                <input id="btnSaveNewClient" type="button" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
                <input id="btnCancelNewClient" type="button" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

and it looks exactly the way I want it to but here is the attachment of what it looks like in the view.
How do i fix it to look like it does in the fiddle?
[image: In MVC View]

Comment: Use you browser tools to inspect the differences between the css in the fiddle and your app. Looks like your using Bootstrap so its likely some other css properties are being set.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I am looking at it right now and the fieldset has a webkit margins and padding and a display block. So I should add these values to my css and zero them out?

Comment: I suspect so. I don't use bootstrap tabs, but I suspect it uses a fieldset so you would need to cancel the in your specific element

Comment: I overrid the values that i seen and it still looks the same. I think I might try just using JQuery tabs instead and see what happens

Comment: I tried using JQuery tabs, but the result is the same..Would it have to do with MVC maybe a style sheet somewhere?

Comment: It looks like an outline is set on the fieldset, try `fieldset {outline: none;}`

Comment: @romuleald, just tried that, didn't change anything. I am looking at the custom.css with mvc and seeing what its doing with the fieldset. So I think I am going to try commenting them out and see how it goes.

Comment: If you add an outline to your fieldset in jsfiddle it looks like the same as your capture!

Comment: I did add an outline in the fiddle and I got a black outlined box around everything

Comment: Found a solution here...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16852484/use-fieldset-legend-with-bootstrap