# Legend Tag Not Rendering Correctly With Bootstrap Grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use the `legend` html tag to visually wrap a set of similar inputs in a form.  It should look similar to how it does when one uses the `legend` attribute without bootstrap, [like is shown here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_fieldset).

I made a bootply example [which is here](http://www.bootply.com/dv2E9t59jA).  As one can see: I am trying to create a legend which wraps the First Name and Last name input fields.  The styling is not right.

I did already look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16852484/use-fieldset-legend-with-bootstrap), but it is different than mine because I am attempting to use a legend within a grid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a way using custom CSS. Just add this CSS, and add `.customLegend` to the `fieldset` that will have a `legend` you want to display this way. Adjust the positioning, padding, etc as needed.

```css
.customLegend {
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  padding: 2em 0 1em;
  margin-top: 2em;
  position: relative;
}
.customLegend legend {
  border: 0;
  background: #fff;
  width: auto;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 1em;
  padding: 0 .5em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <fieldset class="customLegend row">
      <legend>Enter Your Name</legend>
      <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
        <label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
        <label for="last_name">Last Name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pwd">
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Email address:</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
    </div>
    
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```