# Bootstrap well add buttons to edge

Tags: button, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

Currently i have this setup on a page, there are three `buttons` in a button group acting as tab toggle buttons and below them is a bootsrap `well` having tab pages. Is there a way to have the button group become part of the `well`, so it sits in the center of the top edge of the `well`?

I have tried code from here: [Bootstrap - Adding legend to well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12167848/bootstrap-adding-legend-to-well) but didnt work.

Here is img of current setup

[image: picture]

Code is simple

```
    <div style="text-align:center">

    <div id="tab" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
        <a style="padding:9px;font-size:16px" href="#tdel" class="btn active" data-toggle="tab">Delegations</a>
        <a style="padding:9px;font-size:16px" href="#tind" class="btn " data-toggle="tab">Individuals</a>
        <a style="padding:9px;font-size:16px" href="#tobs" class="btn " data-toggle="tab">Observers</a>
    </div>

    </div>



 <div class="well">
     <div class="tab-content">
         <div class="tab-pane" id="tind">
         </div>
         <div class="tab-pane" id="tobs">
         </div>

         <div class="tab-pane" id="tdel">
         </div>

     </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mikeyfreake/CbNfa/2/

Answer (score 0):

Place the `buttonset` div inside the `well` div.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CbNfa/4/) for reference.

You can also margin-top: -15px; in your CSS sheet to further move it up to sit in the center top part of the well. Hope this helps!